# Different. Paperclip working in production and finds aws bucket. But not working in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Hoorah I easily deployed to heroku and found the AWS bucket accordingly. Found a small bug, tried to fix in localhost. Lo' and behold. I get permission denied in local host.

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir
```

All the errors I googled is the opposite of me and can't work in production. For me it's the opposite.

```
# production.rb
# aws paperclip bucket
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV["Bucket"],
        :access_key_id => ENV["AWSAccessKeyId"],
        :secret_access_key => ENV["AWSSecretKey"],
        :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
      }
    }

# development.rb
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

This breaks when I try to save an object with a file attached. I didn't touch anything different but production, and I checked. I'm in development ENV. How do I approach this? The answers I find related are solving the opposite of my problem :l

Edit: If you need me to run a terminal command for more info let me know

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT. It was the initializers that was screwing me up! So even if the paperclip_defaults was in the production config, the paperclip initializer that sets defaults for production was firing. So I simply did this,

```
if Rails.env.development? == false
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
end
```